# Does PHP HipHop support Mysqli library with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, hiphop

We are using Mysqli prepared statements. Please let us know if we can use PHP hiphop and if it supports Mysqli especially prepared statements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cannot you just try? Have you even tried to make any research?

Comment: Are you going to ask this for every feature you may or may not use already? How about just installing it and trying it

Comment: We tried.. it is not supporting... did some search.. couldn't find any info related to this. Hence thought of posting it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue ideling since 10 months regarding this. So i don't think that it work. https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/362

Answer (score 0):

No php Hip-Hop does'nt support **Mysql** but it supports **PDO**

I have also tried it but it did'nt work

For Further information please see below link:-

http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/10/hiphop-for-php-unimplemented-functions-and-features/